# How to only hide the default error message in jquery validate?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a few fields where for Day of Birth field, I'd like to hide the error message when required, but show all other error messages. I've got the following code which hides all error messages:

```
<input type="number" id="DayOfBirth" min="1" max="31" class="input error" name="DayOfBirth" placeholder="DD" aria-invalid="true">
```

The JS:

```
rules = {
    DayOfBirth: required
};
messages = {
    DayOfBirth: "Required field is missing: Day of Birth"
};
$('#myForm').validate({
    rules: rules,
    messages: messages,
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        if (element.attr("name") == "DayOfBirth") {
            error.hide();
        }
        else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        };
    },
})
```

So basically I'd like to hide the default error message ("Required field is missing: Day of Birth") but keep the message for min and max values, How can I do it?

Comment: What is the HTML of the error when printed?

Comment: @Morris in the case of required, the error html is "Required field is missing: Day of Birth"; in the case of a minus number or a value larger than 31, the message should be "Value must be greater than or equal to 1" or "Value must be lessthan or equal to 31"

Comment: @Sparky I defined `min` and `max` values in the html so if a user input the wrong value, wouldn't jQuery-validate pick it up and display the default error message as I showed in my last comment?

Comment: Oh yes, I see what you mean now.  Yes, jQuery Validate will automatically pick up the HTML5 inline validation attributes too.  Updated answer... same solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your whole problem is here...

```
messages = {
    // same message for ALL rules on this field
    DayOfBirth: "Required field is missing: Day of Birth"
};
```

This defines ONE custom message for ALL rules on the field named `DayOfBirth`.

Then as far as conditionally showing the rules based on ONLY the field name, this actually works perfectly fine...

```
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    if (element.attr("name") == "DayOfBirth") { 
        error.hide();  // hide ALL messages for the matching field
    }
    else {
        error.insertAfter(element);
    };
},
```

However, that's going to hide ALL messages for the field called `DayOfBirth`.

In other words, you've set the same custom message for all rules on one field, and yet then hide any/all messages for the same field.  Makes no sense.

---

If you only want to hide the messages for the `required` rule on one specific field, then simply set its custom message to blank...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#myForm').validate({
        rules: {
            foo: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            bar: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            foo: {
                required: "",  // show nothing
                minlength: "foo too short"
            },
            bar: {
                required: "bar is required"
            }
        }
    })

});
```

**DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/e8jwLfb2/](https://jsfiddle.net/e8jwLfb2/)**

---

And like the OP has in his setup; a mix of rules declared via the `.validate()` method along with some inline HTML5 attributes.  It's the same solution since custom messages are defined via the plugin:

**DEMO 2:  [jsfiddle.net/bLn169h2/](https://jsfiddle.net/bLn169h2/)**

When using the `messages` object, you can set custom messages for EACH rule on the field...

```
messages: {
    foo: {
        required: "custom required message for foo field",
        minlength:  "custom minlength message for foo field"
    }
}
```

OR for the entire field...

```
messages: {
    foo: "custom message for all rules on foo field"
}
```

It does not matter how or where each rule was declared, this custom message will over-ride regardless.  So in your case, you defined a custom message on the field name which would override all validation messages for all rules on this field.  Then you have a conditional function in `errorPlacement` that hides "the validation message" for an entire field.  Again, it does not matter where the rule was declared because all rules and messages are coming through the jQuery Validate plugin.

Comment: The first solution was more close to my actual solution, definitely helped, thanks!